# Struts2 Tiles implementation with internationalization with input from database

Tags: database, struts2, internationalization

I am a newbiee to Struts2 tiles. I want to write website having multiple pages and having support for multiple languages. Many pages will have same layout (so using tiles) only login page will have different layout.

I have searched in for reading the language specific Data from Database and have a method ready for it. I have the base layout ready but I am not able to understand how to integrate internationalization and tiles.

Attaching base layout and Database method

DBResourceBundle.java

```
package com.ruukki.webui.util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;



import com.ruukki.webui.vo.ConnectionType;
import com.ruukki.webui.vo.User;

public class DbResourceBundle extends ResourceBundle
{
    private Properties properties;
    public DbResourceBundle(Properties inProperties)
    {
        properties = inProperties;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings(value = { "unchecked" })
    public Enumeration<String> getKeys()
    {
        return properties != null ? ((Enumeration<String>) properties.propertyNames()) : null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object handleGetObject(String key)
    {
        return properties.getProperty(key);
    }

    public static ResourceBundle.Control getMyControl()
    {
        return new ResourceBundle.Control()
        {

            @Override
            public List<String> getFormats(String baseName)
            {
                if (baseName == null)
                {
                    throw new NullPointerException();
                }
                return Arrays.asList("db");
            }

            @Override
            public ResourceBundle newBundle(String baseName, Locale locale, String format, ClassLoader loader, boolean reload) throws IllegalAccessException,
                  InstantiationException, IOException
            {
                if ((baseName == null) || (locale == null) || (format == null) || (loader == null))
                    throw new NullPointerException();
                ResourceBundle bundle = null;
                if (format.equals("db"))
                {
                    Properties p = new Properties();
                    Connection con = null;
                    Statement s = null;
                    ResultSet rs = null;
                    try
                    {
                        con = LocalDbManager.getConnectionForUser(new User("sa","")) ;
                        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
                        query.append("SELECT * FROM Language_Text");
                        int value =3; 
                        if (locale != null)
                        {
                            System.out.println("locale has vlue " + locale.getLanguage());
                            if(locale.getLanguage().equals("en")){
                                value = 3;
                            }else if(locale.getLanguage().equals("fi")){
                                value = 4;
                            }
                        }
                        s = con.createStatement();
                        System.out.println("stmt:" + s);
                        rs = s.executeQuery(query.toString());
                        System.out.println("Executed Query and got data:" + query);

                        System.out.println("Column count" );
                        while (rs.next())
                        {
                            p.setProperty(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(value));
                        }
                        System.out.println("Is property Filleked" + p.isEmpty());
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("failed to build properties file");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        throw new RuntimeException("Can not build properties: " + e);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        ConnectionManager.closeQuietly(con, s, rs);
                    }
                    bundle = new DbResourceBundle(p);
                }
                return bundle;
            }

            @Override
            public long getTimeToLive(String baseName, Locale locale)
            {
                return 1000 * 60 * 30;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean needsReload(String baseName, Locale locale, String format, ClassLoader loader, ResourceBundle bundle, long loadTime)
            {
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

tiles.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>

  <definition name="baseLayout" template="/baseLayout.jsp">
      <put-attribute name="title"  value="Template"/>
      <put-attribute name="header" value="/header.jsp"/>
      <put-attribute name="menu"   value="/menu.jsp"/>
      <put-attribute name="body"   value="/body.jsp"/>
      <put-attribute name="footer"   value="/footer.jsp"/>
  </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

header.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<head>
 <link  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="ruukki.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="header">
<table width="100%"> 
    <tr>
        <td width="10%"><div id="Logo" > <img src="logo.png"> </div></td>
        <td width="50%"><div id="Welcome_Portal"> Welcome to Portal !!! </div>
        <td width="15%"><p align="left" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Welcome, <s:property value="username"/></p></td>
        <td width="2%" align="center"><img alt="" src="Image/flag_en.png"></a></td>
        <td width="2%" align="center"><img alt="" src="Image/flag_fin.png"></td>
        <td width="2%" align="center"><img alt="" src="Image/flag_sw.png"></td>
        <td width="5%"><s:url id="logout" action="logout"/>
            <s:a href="%{logout}" target="_parent">Logout </s:a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

strtus.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>
        <action name="*Link" method="{1}" class="com.tutorials4u.actions.LinkAction">
            <result name="welcome" type="tiles">welcome</result>
            <result name="struts" type="tiles">struts</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

baseLayout.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" align="center" width="100%" height="100%">
            <tr>
                <td height="10%" colspan="2">
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%" height="80%">
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />
                </td>
                <td width="80%" height="80%" style="min-height: 120px">
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="10%" colspan="2">
                    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

With change in language I want to display the Contents from header as per the language selected.

Currently tried with this in the page to have the language contents

```
<%
  ResourceBundle lbls = null;
  ResourceBundle msgs = null;
  try {
      String value = Globals.LOCALE_KEY.toString();
      System.out.println("value: " + value);
      Locale locale = new Locale("fi","");
      lbls = ResourceBundle.getBundle("AwesomeBundle", locale, DbResourceBundle.getMyControl());
  } catch (Exception ex) {

  }

%>
```

But I want it to be used in all pages...So a bit confused. And Sorry if it is too stupied question.

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/localization.html.

Comment: Hi Aleksandr M
So are u suggesting I should pass the resource bundle in session? Actually I want to use them to have language specific text display like in for labels.

    <td width="50%"><div id="Welcome_Portal"> Welcome to Portal !!! </div>  So thata Welcome to portal must be in different languages. Can you please proive some Example for the same. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Follow and **read** link that I gave you.